# How to perform a simple calculation to with my bash script variables in gnuplot

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have variables M_i and M > M_i. I want to make a splot where one of the columns of my data file is evaluated using these variables...

Something like this:

`splot "9.90000000orbs.dat" u 1:2:(10+4*($M-$M_i))`

I can't figure out the correct syntax for the last column specification. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a syntax error? Or is the output different from what you want?

Comment: Yes, there is a syntax error.

Comment: In this case the (10+4*($M-$M_i)) is evaluated, but the splot plots all the x,y (col1,col2) values with the value of (10+4*($M-$M_i)), so my splot is a simply red square in x and y. I have tried many other ways of expressing the (10+4*($M-$M_i)) part, generally resulting in syntax errors.

Comment: But if `M` and `M_i` are fixed, the evaluation should also be fixed.

Comment: So (10+4*($M-$M_i)) is fixed (say 14), but I want to use that value to specify the column, not the value of the plot. So currently this command plots a red square with value 14 but it should be a pretty graph where the colour is determined by the values in the 14th column of 9.90000000orbs.dat.

Comment: So without the variables, the code would be e.g.

splot "9.90000000orbs.dat" u 1:2:14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve this:
Specify a function to use as the third plot argument.

```
x(x) = x
splot "9.90000000orbs.dat" u 1:2:x(10+4*(M-M_i))
```

Note, that you have to discard the `$` before `M` and `M_i` respectively. Now, if `(10+4*(M-M_i))=14`, the function `x(x)` will ensure that you plot `x(14)` which is the 14th column.

It worked for me using a simple test case and gnuplot 4.6

Comment: Beautiful, that sorted it out for me! Was the problem then that the column specification simply can't perform computations with variables?

Comment: @DennisAddison basically, yes. gnuplot wouldn't understand that (as the syntax error tried to tell you)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough.
Let's say you want to plot column 4 when data of column 3 are greater than variable m =>

```
if (!exist("m")){m=14}
splot "9.90000000orbs.dat" u 1:2:($3<m ? $3: $4)
```

or give two line example of your file and more explanation.

You can invoke from bash using :

```
$> gnuplot file.plt -e "m=$M"
```